# Generating REST api documentation in spring jersey rest

Tags: spring, swagger

My project exposes rest api through Jersey along with spring and spring data at backend.
I want to implement REST api documentation, in my project.
Any ideas, as how can I achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/) is probably the most common library for integration with JAX-RS projects to produce Swagger definitions. Its wiki contains the relevant information on how to integrate it with your code (including sample projects).